# Difference in values

Tags: sql

I have a table with values similar to image 1. I want a column which gives the difference between High values and Low Values keeping the medium values same as the difference.

[image: Current Table]

[image: Result expected]

Please let me know if you have nay questions.
Thanks
Sam

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your RDBMS, that you did not specify, supports window functions, you could use a conditional window max to compute the difference between the high and low value of each date partition:

```
select
    t.*,
    max(case when project = 'High' then value end) over(partition by date) 
        - max(case when project = 'Low' then value end) over(partition by date) result 
from mytable t
```

Without window functions, you can compute the result of each date in a subquery and join it to the original table, as follows:

```
select
    t.*,
    x.result
from mytable t
inner join (
    select 
        date,
        max(case when project = 'High' then value end) 
            - max(case when project = 'Low' then value end) result
    from mytable
    group by date
) x on x.date = t.date
```